# Running OpenCV on Raspberry PI

Tags: linux, opencv, raspberry-pi

I am trying to test a simple example program on Raspberry PI, to start test OpenCV function on Raspberry PI.

After successful compilation, I get an empty window.

The code is an example code when could be found on the OpenCV website, however the only part I change is name of the picture.

```
IplImage* img = cvLoadImage("pic1.jpg", 3);
```

All I get in an empty window. The `pic.jpg` is saved in the home directory`(home/pi)`.

Anyone came across this before?

Regards

Comment: rule 1: if it has iplimages, avoid it ! please try to avoid opencv's deprecated c-api, use the c++ one instead.

Answer (score 1):

Make sure object file and jpg that you're trying to load is in the same directory. (home)

Or just use complete path like this.

IplImage* img = cvLoadImage("/home/pi/pic1.jpg", 3);

Hope it helps.